# Failed to access samba shared directory, Log port error, protocol not found

Tags: samba, centos6.4

I tried to configure samba server for internal sharing purpose. I can access the global environment but when I tried to access directory environment, it is failed.

I checked to log file of samba and I found below error, I tried to googling it but, unfortunately not found any sign of solutions.

```
[2014/02/25 16:59:43.905575,  0] lib/util_sock.c:628(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 139 failed with error = Protocol not available
[2014/02/25 17:04:14.386298,  0] lib/util_sock.c:628(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 445 failed with error = Protocol not available
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion regarding this error?

I am using Samba 3.6.9-167.el6_5 on CentOS 6.4.

Comment: I also have these errors in my logs (debug level 3) but i am able to access Samba shared folders. I think this error is not the root cause for your issue. To be sure, check if port 445 and 139 are listening correctly using `netstat`

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm facing same plobrem.Please tell me how did you solve it if you've done it.